# Корректный QuerySet в Django по реляционным моделям с условием

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-orm, queryset

Модели:

```
Tticket(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    status = models.ForeignKey('TStatus') 

Sticket(models.Model):
    create_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    close_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    tticket = models.ForeignKey('Tticket')

TticketLifecycle(models.Model)
    start_dt = models.DateTimeField()
    end_dt = models.DateTimeField()
    tticket = models.ForeignKey('Tticket')
    status = models.ForeignKey('TStatus')
```

На выходе надо получить Tticket_id, суммарное время жизни Tticket на определённых статусах, количество Sticket связанных с Tticket и их суммарное время жизни.
Для этого составляю Qset:

```
date_delta = ExpressionWrapper(F("end_dt") - F("start_dt"), DurationField())
date_delta_null = ExpressionWrapper(Now() - F("start_dt"), DurationField())
st_date_delta = ExpressionWrapper(
    F('tticket__sticket__close_datetime')-F('tticket__sticket__create_datetime'),
    DurationField()
)
st_date_delta_null = ExpressionWrapper(
    Now() - F('tticket__sticket__create_datetime'), DurationField()
)

tt_lc = TticketLifecycle.objects.filter(status_id__in=[1,3])
res = tt_lc.annotate(tt_id=F('tticket_id')).values('tt_id').annotate(
            ttl=Sum(Case(When(end_dt__isnull=True, then=date_delta_null),default=date_delta)),
            st_count=Count('tticket__sticket', distinct=True),
            st_sum_ttl=Sum(
                    Case(
                        When(tticket__sticket__close_datetime__isnull=True, then=st_date_delta_null), default=st_date_delta
                    )
            )).values('tt_id', 'ttl', 'st_count', 'st_sum_ttl')
```

tt_lc - возвращает две записи, обе записи имеют один Tticket.
res - в значение st_sum_ttl возвращается сумма без учёта дублей объектов модели sticket. Т.е. tt_lc[0].tticket.stticket_set == tt_lc[1].tticket.stticket_set, как составить запрос таким образом, чтобы при вычислении времени sticket учитывались только уникальные объекты?